# Why does the generated form's validation check the changeset's `:action` field instead of `:valid?`?

Tags: phoenix-framework

For example, issuing the

```
mix phx.gen.html Accounts User users name:string age:integer
```

command [from the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Html.html) would generate [`form.html.eex`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/priv/templates/phx.gen.html/form.html.eex):

```
<%%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <%% end %>
<%= for {label, input, error} <- inputs, input do %>
  <%= label %>
  <%= input %>
  <%= error %>
<% end %>
  <div>
    <%%= submit "Save" %>
  </div>
<%% end %>
```

Is there a reason for not checking `@changeset.valid? == false` instead?

The current form is indeed shorter, and it has been educational to learn that the `:action` key is `nil` only, when there has been no errors.

Is there any other consideration that one would need to take into account (e.g., adding more fields later), or this is just a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow missed the [`Phoenix.HTML.Form` documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html), where in the "***A note on* `:errors`**" section it says that

> If no action has been applied to the changeset or action was set to
>   `:ignore`, no errors are shown on the form object even if the changeset
>   has a non-empty `:errors` value.
>
> This is useful for things like validation hints on form fields, e.g.
>   an empty changeset for a new form. That changeset isn’t valid, but we
>   don’t want to show errors until an actual user action has been
>   performed.

An empty changeset is indeed invalid by default:

```
iex> %Ecto.Changeset{}
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [], data: nil, valid?: false>
```